# Custom text colors on wordpress product page

Tags: css, wordpress, button, colors

I am really new to all this so please keep that in mind :/

I have removed the "add to cart" button from the theme (blocksy) to be able to add my own button within the product page itself  under the "short description" text (I needed 2 "download" button, one for mac one for PC). Here is the code I used in the short description :

**Downloads**
Mac Windows

Right now the text seams to be the same color as the background (here is how it looks like : https://zerocentsaudio.com/produit/tunefish-4/

And I can not find a way to change the text color.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `content` for your button `before` selector. Try this code to unset it.

```css
.theme-blocksy .button:before{
    content: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

I hope I helped

```css
.theme-blocksy .button:before {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit precise on that particular button(s)-

```
.woocommerce-product-details__short-description .button {
    color: red;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.woocommerce-product-details__short-description .button:before {
    content: unset;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for you help, I have tried this but it looks like the background color is "taking over" (or on top maybe ?) and even with 0 opacity it still won't show the text on the button. It does work on mobile for some reason ? ...

Comment: It could be a possibility that your desktop browser cached the CSS. Try doing a hard reload by pressing CTRL/CMD and pressing the reload icon at the same time (or visit the page from incognito). If still no luck, you can add 'content: unset !important;' declaration which should overwrite other declarations. NOTE: your server is caching the previous CSS I guess. The new CSS declarations aren't loading at all.